# Prove the following statement by contrapositive: If $a_n$ - $a_0$ $\gt n$, then there exists $i\in [n]$ such that $a_i$ - $a_{i-1}$ $\gt 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Basically in the title, with the let statement: Let $a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$. I'm confused on how to assume the contrapositive in this case and the actual proof. Would it be that if there doesn't exist such an $i$, then this?

Comment: Yes.  The contrapositive would be: If there does not exist any $i \in [n]$ such that $a_i - a_{i-1} > 1$, then $a_n - a_0 \le n$.  The proof is straightforward... by induction on $n$, say.